# How to find specific dynamic class name checkbox?

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I have successfully generated dynamic checkboxes, I am trying to make a select all function to select some specific checkboxes. all the check boxes has a dynamic class name as follow

** HTML **

```
    <input type="checkbox"  value="None" id="itemselect" class="NP<seperator><?php echo $productId; ?>" name="itemselect" />
```

and some other check boxes are generated as:

```
<input type="checkbox"  value="None" id="itemselect" class="OS<seperator><?php echo $productId; ?>" name="itemselect" />
```

What I have to do is to select class="NP........"  on select all checkbox checked.

I have checked stack overflow and I found the bellow suggestion that, kind of answering my issue but in the alert I get object object while I supposed to get NP separator and the productId.

Please help me to find out what is wrong with my code.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

 $("#itemselectall").on("click", function() {
    var all = $(this);
    $('input:checkbox').each(function() {
    var classchkd =   $(this).attr('class', all.attr('class'));
alert (classchkd);
 });
 });
 });
```

Comment: You shouldn't have more than one element with a particular id, so `id="itemselect"` should only occur once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "starts with" selector:

```
$('[class^="NP"]').prop('checked', true)
```

However, it would make more sense to separate out your classes:

```
<input type="checkbox"  value="None" id="itemselect" class="NP NP<seperator><?php echo $productId; ?>" name="itemselect" />
```

Then, you can simply select all of them with:

```
$('.NP').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: appreciated your reply, It works perfectly and its much simpler. $('.NP').prop('checked', true);  Could you vote up my question too? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I created a small example.

**HTML:**

```
<button id="loadBox">load a checkbox</button>
<button id="toggleBoxes">toggle all boxes</button>
<div id="container">
</div>
```

**javascript:**

```
var counter = 1;
$("#loadBox").click(function(){
    $("#container").append("<input type='checkbox' class='NP1'>" +
                           "checkbox " + counter + "</input><br>");
    counter++;
})
var flipper = true;
$("#toggleBoxes").click(function(){
    $(".NP1").each(function(){
        $(this).prop("checked", flipper);
    })
    if (flipper)
        $("#toggleBoxes").text("uncheck all");
    else
        $("#toggleBoxes").text("check all");
    flipper = !flipper;
})
```

Clicking the `#loadBox` button adds a checkbox to the `#container` `<div>`. You can adjust this function as necessary to change the class (or load them with PHP—how you do it is mostly irrelevant).

Clicking the `toggle all boxes` button either makes them all checked or all unchecked, depending on what they were last. The key is to alter how you select them. In this case, I used `$(".NP1")`. This will change according to the classes you load, so you will need to run a variable through the selector which is set to the input class you want to check or uncheck.

## [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/NMFX9/1/)